# How to remove all style sheet using ganon DOM parser

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, ganon

I am using [ganon](http://code.google.com/p/ganon/)(http://code.google.com/p/ganon/) **DOM** parser to manipulate the html content.

I need to manupulate the given html page. For that first I need to remove all stylesheet (link tags) from dom. But I didnt find any function to remove all the stylesheet. Only I found the function to remove the stylesheet one by one. I adding the code that I worked. Anyone have an idea how to remove all the style sheets, please help.

```
include_once('ganon.php');
$html  = file_get_dom('http//www.example.com');
$head  = $html->select("head", 0);
$head->select('link', 0)->delete();//this is delete only the first stylesheet
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I got a solution to remove all the stylesheet from dom. Please look at the code

```
foreach($html->select('link[rel="stylesheet"]') as $element){
    $element->delete();
}
```

Thanks